# Programmatically Updating Products changes Custom Option & MetaData scope

Tags: custom-options, object-manager, scope, magento-2.1.10, scope-switcher

I am working on a free standing script that updates product price and I have noticed that the scope of the product's custom options change after execution, causing the 'Use Default Value' to become unchecked.

```
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
    $storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);
    $product = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
    $product->setStoreId(0);
    $product->setPrice($price);
    $product->setTaxClassId(0);
    $product->save();
```

I have seen some solutions posed that run a query to delete the options where store_id = 1 but am curious if there is a way to avoid the extra step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line

```
$state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
```

to

```
$state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
```

and chnage below for line as

```
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->setTaxClassId(0);
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It would appear that this was exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, can you explain why this works? I'm pretty novice with Magento.